# Get filename in Mapper hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, filenames, mapper, keyerror

My mapper is organized as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys    

for line in sys.stdin:
    filename = os.environ["map_input_file"]
    print(filename)
```

I'm just trying to get the filename in the mapper, but there is an error on the map_input_file defined as follows:

```
"File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
     raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'map_input_file'"
```

I'm confused about what might be the issue as I tried different things such as:

```
try:
    filename = os.environ["mapreduce.map.input.file"]
except KeyError:
    filename = os.environ["map.input.file"]
```

or

```
try:
    filename = os.environ["mapreduce_map_input_file"]
except KeyError:
    filename = os.environ["map_input_file"]
```

It always raises a `KeyError` and cannot import the filename.

Any solution on how to get the filename in a mapper would be much appreciated.

For info, I am running this code locally using a cat text.txt | mapper.py pipeline. Running it on a cluster, my end goal, wouldn't work either, probably because of the same error.

Comment: You don't have `map_input_file`, `mapreduce_map_input_file` or any other keys you try in your enviroment variables dict. Can you exlpain what you tyring to do?

Comment: @Ilko I was trying to run it in a cluster with AWS, and I thought this is where it wasn't working because there was a problem in the mapper and I'm pretty sure the rest of the code works fine. But running it locally might not work as the environment variable isn't set.

Answer (score -1):

@Ilko Indeed, trying to run it on a cluster gives me the following error:

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1550240953895_0001_m_000005_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169)

19/02/15 14:41:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 6% reduce 0%
19/02/15 14:41:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
19/02/15 14:41:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1550240953895_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1550240953895_0001_m_000008
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
```

Which isnt really helpful for someone as inexperienced as me haha